# display number of items in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I need a very easy thing and looking on the web the solutions founded tell me that my code is right. But clearly isn't.
I just need to display how many notes(models) I have in my app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Notes and bookmarks </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">  
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="bar">
        <input type="text" class="search" />
        <div class="bar-buttons">
          <button> NEW </button>
          <button> HOME </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4 class="all-notes">All Notes {{all}}</h4>
          {{#each item in model}}
            <li>
              {{#link-to 'note' item}} {{item.title}} {{/link-to}}
            </li>
          {{/each}}
      </aside>
      {{outlet}}
    </div> 
</script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main"> 
 <section>
 <h2>Hellooo</h2>
 </section>
 </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="note"> 
    <section>
        <div class="note">
            {{#if isEditing}}
              <h2 class="note-title input-title"> {{edit-input-note value=title focus-out="modified" insert-newline="modified"}} </h2>
              <p class="input-body"> {{edit-area-note value=body focus-out="modified" insert-newline="modified"}} </p>
              {{edit-input-note value=url focus-out="modified" insert-newline="modified"}}
            {{else}}
              <h2 {{action "editNote" on="doubleClick"}} class="note-title" > {{title}} </h2>
              <button {{action "removeNote"}} class="delete"> Delete </button>
              <p {{action "editNote" on="doubleClick"}}> {{body}} </p>
              {{input type="text" placeholder="URL:" class="input"  value=url }}
            {{/if}}
        </div>
      </section>
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models/note_model.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/note_controller.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/notes_controller.js"></script>
  <script src="js/views/note_view.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My model:

```
    Notes.Note = DS.Model.extend ({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
});

Notes.Note.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'hello world',
        body: 'ciao ciao ciao ciao',
        url: ''
    },
    {   
        id: 2,
        title: 'javascript frameworks',
        body: 'Backbone.js, Ember.js, Knockout.js',
        url: '...'

    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Find a job in Berlin',
        body: 'Monster, beralinstartupjobs.com',
        url: '...'
    }
]
```

And my notes controller:

```
Notes.NotesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend ({
    all: function () {
        var notes = this.get('model');
        return notes.get('lenght');
    }.property('model')
});
```

I think that's all the important code for make this work but if you need others part I will add.
Why i can't see the number of my notes in {{all}} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `notes.hbs` template you should be able to do `{{length}}`.

Comment: oh... it was so easy, and i was going crazy for find an ember solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a few adjustments to the code that you provided and got it to work the way that i think you expected it to work. I am going to try to explain where I think you may have been sent for a loop as it relates to your App. Ember takes some getting use to for sure.

One thing that is important is that Ember uses naming conventions to help you wire up and associate your Router, Routes, Controllers, Templates correctly with each other and also help you to look at code and know what Ember expects. Ember also gives you free stuff, yaaay for free stuff.

So when Ember boots up you get some default assets for free the `ApplicationRoute`, `ApplicationController`, and the `application` template these are always present in Ember even if you never explicitly define them. However if you need to use them just define them and add whatever code. In addition to those you get an `IndexRoute`, `IndexController` and `index` template which are present at the top of Ember like those other assets.

Remember the `application` template, which is at the highest level of the app, think of it as the parent of all templates. Other templates will be put into it and rendered, including the `index` template that you got for free. Now this is where things get a little tricky.

If you define a router like this in Ember for example. You still have that `index` template which you can use as you were and you also now have a template called `note`.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('note');
});
```

Can you guess the names for the Controller and Route associated with the `note` resource using Ember naming conventions? I'll leave that for homework. Now when Ember boots with this Router if you defined a `index` template (just like you were) it will automatically be pushed into the `application` templates `{{outlet}}`and rendered. A note on the `application` template if all its doing is basically being and 'outlet' to render stuff Ember will do that just fine by default.

Behind the scenes the default `application` template may look something like this. I just put the `<script>` tags to highlight its the `application` template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

The template without a data-template-name is used as the application template. You can put in `data-template-name="application"` if you like but its not necessary unless you are using build tools. Now back to the Router stuff.

If you define a Router like this something happens that is important to realize.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('note', { path: '/'});
});
```

By adding `{path: '/'}` in that resource you are overriding the `/`, which is the based url of you application. Now '/' is not associated with `index` template that you got for free its the `note` template. When Ember boots it will automatically push the `note` template into the `application` outlet.

Moving along, in your code you had few other things that were also conflicting. Remember with naming conventions if ask `Notes.NotesController` for something Ember by default will look for a `Notes.NotesRoute` and a `notes` template, attention to the pluralization, but in your code your code you have a `note` template.

The other conflict is with the `index` template, again with the naming conventions Ember is going to look for the `IndexController` for the `{{all}}` property and `IndexRoute` to the supply the model. In your code its on the `Notes.NotesController`.

And finally dont forget if you are using and adapter to define it:

```
 Notes.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
```

Sorry for the long answer but i hope it clear up things

Here the jsBin.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UPaYIwO/7/edit

Happy Coding!!

PS. You could have put {{model.length}} in the template and it would have accomplished the same thing. But in Ember there is a few ways to do the same thing.

There is also a typo:

```
return notes.get('lenght');
```

Lenght should be length;

```
return notes.get('length');
```

Comment: Really I thought u got it working. I messed around and got it to work. I can amend my answer if you want later I should have saved the jsbin and posted. I read the answer below and thought it was set.